# swap uuid on boot

Tags: boot, swap, fstab, uuid

I am a beginner (please be patient :)) and have a question regarding swap uuid. 
A couple a days ago I have played with swap space and ever since the boot process slowed down. What I did:
swapoff, tried to shrink space (with `dd`), didn't work, made another swap (`mkswap`), `swapon`, got new swap uuid, modified `/etc/fstab`, and (problem..) got a boot delay.

Right now:

blkid (extract):

```
/dev/sda3: UUID="8910bdea-290d-4d18-8a80-b08b34d6b6e6" TYPE="swap" PARTLABEL="UBUSWAP" PARTUUID="2eabd59f-a929-44d6-97e8-b8eb737be2a2"
```

disk-by-uuid (extract):

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 feb 13 10:58 8910bdea-290d-4d18-8a80-b08b34d6b6e6 -> ../../sda3
```

fstab (extract):

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=8910bdea-290d-4d18-8a80-b08b34d6b6e6 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

and the problem: /var/log/boot.log

```
[  OK  ] Activated swap Swap Partition.
[  OK  ] Activated swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/d4ddd25a-14cc-4e10-a227-86150694c014.
[  OK  ] Reached target Swap.

[**    ] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-d4ddd25a\x2d…d4e10\x2da227\x2d8615
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-d4ddd25a\x2d14cc\x2d4e10\x2da227\x2d86150694c014.device.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /dev/disk/by-uuid/d4ddd25a-14cc-4e10-a227-86150694c014.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Swap.
```

I can see that Ubuntu still knows about old swap uuid (d4ddd25a...) and is ignoring the `/etc/fstab` entry. I reinstalled the kernel, rebooted..the same problem. The system is working but the boot time increased a lot.

I looked in grub.conf and other places, nothing came out.

```
sudo find / -iname '*' | grep d4ddd25a
```

returned

```
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
```

Nothing found in `grub.conf`

I am stuck and got no idea what to do.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problem. After some searching and testing solutions I was able to solve this problem.

Try with this:

```
sudo swapoff /dev/sdXY 
sudo mkswap /dev/sdXY 
sudo swapon /dev/sdxy
```

Note, if you do this, mkswap will create a new UUID for your swap partition, so if you use UUIDs in your fstab, you have to update it.

That part didn't solve my problem but might be helpful.
After changing UUID in /etc/fstab, I did

`"update-initramfs -u"`

but that helped me partially (only default kernel was updated) because I have mainline kernel installed.

If you have mainline kernel too, you have to add -k, to specify what version of kernel you want to update:

`"update-initramfs -k (kernel version) -u"`

After that, boot delay was gone.